# Wrapping c++ using both Cython and SWIG

Tags: python, c++, wrapper, swig, cython

There is a library written in C++. I have tried various ways to wrap it in Python as an extension module.

First, I used Cython to write the wrappers. The issue there is that there are so many functions that it is very time consuming.

I recently tried to start over with SWIG. SWIG is a wrapper generator which automates creating wrapper code for C++ into scripting languages. I used SWIG to generate wrappers quickly for 90% of the library.

The problem here is that SWIG has trouble with some portions of the library, ex. stl containers, for instance `std::set<foo*>` that I can wrap manually with Cython.

Is it possible to wrap most of the library in SWIG, and use Cython to wrap the difficult parts by hand?

Clarifications: I am not trying to ask HOW to wrap C++ into Python. I can generate a wrapping that works for most functions using SWIG, and I can hand-write wrappers in Cython for the problem bits. The question is: How can I combine the two wrapping approaches to get the best of both worlds?

Comment: SWIG works with c++ directly. What is the question then? Use the C++ binding of the SWIG. The difference in calling and naming conventions, so you need a kind of wrapper to call C++ from C.

Comment: In a similar position, I wrote an interface that uses the library and does what needs to be done, and then used (python extension module of choice) to make that interface usable from python.  Making everything in the c++ library directly usable in python would have been impractical and untestable, plus exceptions would have been problematic.

Comment: @Tanuki The challenge is not getting SWIG to work with c++, it is getting c++ to work with Python using SWIG.

Comment: @ratiotile Hmm, then have a look at libffi.

Comment: @KennyOstrom: the library is an api, and I would rather have a complete wrapping (minus parts that I never need, with %ignore) than have to go back and reimplement functions that I thought I wouldn't need later.